# Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type float, table 'TABLE', column 'FECHA'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have this error, and I can't fix it

Msg 260, Level 16, State 3, Procedure SP_SAV_ESTADISTICALLAMADAXOPERADOR, Line 7
Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type float, table 'APEX.SAV_LLAMADAS', column 'FECHA'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

this's my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE APEX.SP_SAV_ESTADISTICALLAMADAXOPERADOR
    @pCodOperador   VARCHAR (20) 
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT  TP.DESCRIPCION AS TIPOLOGIA,
                ST.DESCRIPCION AS SUB_TIPOLOGIA,
                COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
        FROM    APEX.SAV_LLAMADAS_DET DT INNER JOIN APEX.SAV_LLAMADAS LL 
        ON      LL.ID_LLAMADA  = DT.ID_LLAMADA  INNER JOIN APEX.SAV_SUB_TIPOLOGIAS ST 
        ON      DT.COD_TIPOLOGIA  = DT.COD_TIPOLOGIA
         AND    DT.COD_SUBTIPOLOGIA  = ST.COD_SUB_TIPOLOGIA  INNER JOIN APEX.SAV_TIPOLOGIAS TP 
        ON      TP.COD_TIPOLOGIA  = ST.COD_TIPOLOGIA  
        WHERE   DT.USUARIO_CREA  = @pCodOperador
         AND    FLOOR(LL.FECHA)  = FLOOR((GETDATE()))
        GROUP BY TP.DESCRIPCION, ST.DESCRIPCION 

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do FLOOR on a datetime datatype. Assuming you are trying to exclude the time portion of a datetime you can do something like this instead.

```
AND CAST(LL.FECHA AS DATE)  = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: That's right, thank you very much, works to perfection